# Idiomatically, should python context managers acquire resources at initialization, or when entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, idioms, raii, contextmanager

In general, I really like the explicitness of Python's context managers (CMs), but have been having trouble dealing with their inherent ambiguity. Specifically, without looking at a CM's code, it's often not possible to figure out *when* it will acquire its resources.

For instance, the object returned from `open()` is [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) - it acquires its file handle immediately upon initialization.

```py
f = open('file.txt', 'r')  # opens file or raises exception
with f as stream:
   [...]
```

I've seen this pattern in many places: the resource is acquired immediately on initialization; entering the context does nothing; and exiting the context releases the resource.

Contrarily, the `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator creates CMs that do the opposite: they do nothing upon initialization, and defer all setup until the context is entered. In Python, this is certainly safer than RAII, because it guarantees cleanup (well, unless the caller directly calls `__enter__`).

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def iter_lines(path):
   with open(path, 'r') as stream:
      yield stream.readlines()

line_iter = iter_lines("file.txt")  # does NOT open file, always succeeds
with line_iter as stream:  # opens file or raises exception
   [...]
```

Is there a preferred idiomatic way to deal with this ambiguity? I can think of a couple ideas:

1. Accept the ambiguity and hope that the docstring tells you what kind of CM you're dealing with; or
2. Only initialize CMs in a `with` statement, nowhere else. If you can't construct and enter the CM on the same line, create a lambda that can be called to construct the object and pass *that*. The 2nd example above would become:

```py
line_iter = lambda: iter_lines("file.txt")
[...]
with line_iter() as stream:
   [...]
```

Is there an idiom that I'm missing - some "right way" to use context managers - that resolves this ambiguity?

Comment: I think the usual solution is #2. It's very rare to see the call separate from `with`.

Comment: IMO unnecessary to go as far as creating a lambda -- it's sufficient to just keep initialization close by. Python is not a purely referentially transparent language (though IMO code is often better when it is). I think wrapping in lambda won't even save you from exceptions raised from initialization, you'd have to wrap the context in your own context for that.